# how to decode image data with JSON format in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, escaping, json

In Rails 3, I want to post the bitmap image data in JSON format to server, so I do the following steps. 
1. In client, translate the bitmap image to string. 
2. Encode the string in JSON format and post to the server. 
3. Decode the bitmap image data of JSON format. 
Now the problem is: 
 In bitmap image, there are many 0 bytes or other unreadable bytes, after encoding in JSON format, 0 byte will be translated to /u0000, space byte will to /u000a. 
In the server end, I use *ActiveResource::Formats::JsonFormat.decode* to decode the JSON string, but the method will stop when it meets /u0000, for example,
  JSON string "\u0066\u0066\u0000\u0066\u0066" will be decoded to be "ff", and the rest three bytes will be discarded silently. 
So how to resolve this problem? should I write a function to decode the JSON string myself?

Answer (score 3):

You should really be POSTing that data as binary in a multipart form.

If you must encode it into a string, [use base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426694).

Comment: But expect the base64 version to be a lot bigger, and to take more CPU time to encode, transfer and decode.